# How to get hand mesh data from Hololens2 without turning on Hand Mesh Visualization option

Tags: hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I have tried to get hand mesh data from **Hololens2** using MRTK V2 and Unity C#.
Now, I can get hand mesh data **with turning on Hand Mesh Visualization option** and referring [MRTK HandTracking guide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/HandTracking.html).

Unfortunately, the visualization(drawing hand CG) is heavy workload.
So, I would like to get hand mesh without turning on Hand Mesh Visualization option but [OnHandMeshUpdated](https://hololabinc.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityHandMeshHandler.html) function is not called due to **turning off** Hand Mesh Visualization option.

Does anyone know how to get hand mesh data from Hololens2 without turning on Hand Mesh Visualization option?

[Hand Mesh Visualization option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCsZ0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MRTK does not directly provide this feature. According to the source code of MRTK-Unity, check out the code [line 163 of `BaseHandVisualizer` class](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/375f306d0af44e26335297b2fc988f4d612bf787/Assets/MRTK/Core/Providers/Hands/BaseHandVisualizer.cs), you will find the majority of jobs are processed in the `OnHandMeshUpdated` event handler. When the current hand mesh is updated based on the passed-in state of the hand, `OnHandMeshUpdated` method will be invoked with `HandMeshInfo` event data. Once `Hand Mesh Prefab` field in [InputSystem]->[Hand Tracking] is set as "None", MRTK will not instantiate handMeshFilter according to the conditional statement. But the hand mesh related data will be easily accessible from the event data. Check out the class definition of `HandMeshInfo` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/375f306d0af44e26335297b2fc988f4d612bf787/Assets/MRTK/Core/Interfaces/InputSystem/Handlers/IMixedRealityHandMeshHandler.cs#L20).

Comment: Hi Hernando. Thank you very much for your reply. This is exactly what I want to do. I set "Hand Mesh Prefab" as "None" and it works.